# Creating multiple dataframes from one based on every row above a certain value

Tags: r, grepl

I currently have an excel sheet which is the general format of a class of spreadsheets my company uses. The rows are not fixed but they usually look something like this

```
ID  work_order  Item                            value
1               hero                            9399393
2               zero                            393030
3               hereto                          3322
4               Subsidy Transfer 2018 Medium    9292
5   203         akron                           17272
6   002         saffron                         2345
7   004         Percentage Dispersed            2222
8   005         hi                              105
9   203         bye                             202
10  202         END          
11    
12 UNFORMATTED DATA
```

So I would like to chop this into three distinct dataframes.
1. Every row before and including the call_type beginning with "Subsidy Transfer"
2. Every row after "Subsidy Transfer" and everything before and including "Percentage Dispersed"
3. Every row after "Percentage Dispersed" and before and including "END"

So I have code that will definitely find the row I am looking for...

```
df[grep("Subsidy Transfer", df$Item), ]
```

But I am unsure how to replicate this for the three groups to get three objects while also preserving the variable names. Essentially, everything above and below the three scenarios if that makes sense.

In the end I would like to see three distinct data frames for me to manipulate with the above specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the Item column for grouping, so I simplified your data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
workflow <- data.frame(
    Item = c("a","c","d","Subsidy Transfer 2018 Medium ","a","g","f","d","Percentage Dispersed  ","e","END")
)
```

```
> workflow
                            Item
1                              a
2                              c
3                              d
4  Subsidy Transfer 2018 Medium 
5                              a
6                              g
7                              f
8                              d
9         Percentage Dispersed  
10                             e
11                           END
```

### To answer your question

You need to mark the key rows(e.g. with label 1,2,3) and use `tidyr::fill()` to fill the missing values with the label of key rows.

```
result <- workflow %>%
    mutate(group = case_when(
        grepl("^Subsidy Transfer",Item) ~ 1L,
        grepl("^Percentage Dispersed",Item) ~ 2L,
        grepl("^END",Item) ~ 3L
    )) %>%
    fill(group,.direction = "up") %>%
    group_by(group)

result_list <- group_split(result)
```

```
> result_list
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Item                            group
  <fct>                           <int>
1 a                                   1
2 c                                   1
3 d                                   1
4 "Subsidy Transfer 2018 Medium "     1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Item                     group
  <fct>                    <int>
1 a                            2
2 g                            2
3 f                            2
4 d                            2
5 "Percentage Dispersed  "     2

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Item  group
  <fct> <int>
1 e         3
2 END       3
```

Comment: where did you get the function "fill" ?

Comment: `tidyr::fill()` from `tidyr` package. Just modified my answer to include the packages I use.

Comment: hm okay it works except it does not include the "Subsidy Transfer" , "Percent Dispersed" or "END" rows in their respective groups

Comment: Modified solution so they are in separate groups.

Comment: what i meant is that the "END" row is not reading as 3, nor percentage as 2, etc.instead they start renumbering at the new thing

Comment: It works perfectly fine in the example I provided. Is your actual data different? Or have you loaded any other packages? Try use `tidyr::fill()` and `dplyr::mutate()`

Answer (score 1):

Using the `stringr` package, because the `grep` family of functions aren't vectorized.

```
df$split <- cumsum(stringr::str_detect(df$call_type, "Subsidy Transfer|Percentage|END")) # Identify cutoff rows
df$split <- df$split - stringr::str_detect(df$call_type, "Subsidy Transfer|Percentage|END") # Make cutoff rows belong to the preceding group

split(df, df$split) # split by these groups
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this?:

you can create an empty list where you save the 3 data frames splitted:

```
df_split<-list()

df_split<-list(df[1:which(df$Item=="Subsidy Transfer 2018 Medium"),], 
               df[(1+which(df$Item=="Subsidy Transfer 2018 Medium")):which(df$Item=="Percentage Dispersed"),],
               df[which(df$Item=="Percentage Dispersed") +1:length(df),])
```